# Alternative of cat() and sprintf() to write output faster in a file

Tags: r, connected-components

I'm a newbie in R and pre-processing a big data of million lines to label the connected component and sending the output to a file. But It is taking aweful lot of time using for loop and cat(). Is there any alternative way to write the output file in most faster way in R? I am sharing a sample of code. Any alternative methods or rewriting it with a function that makes it more efficient would be highly appreciated.

```
#Simple example of undirected graph
g <- graph_from_literal(a--b, a--c, b--c, d--e)
plot(g)

#Connected components
#The option, mode, is ignored for undirected graphs
comp <- components(g, mode = "weak")

#output to a file
fout <- file("output.txt", "w")
for (v in V(g)) {

  vn <- V(g)$name[v]
  comp_id <- comp$membership[vn][[1]]
  comp_size <- comp$csize[comp_id]
  cat(sprintf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", vn, comp_id, comp_size), file=fout)

}

close(fout)
```

Comment: *"I am sharing a sample of code"* ... where? Can't really help you with what you've given so far.

Comment: #Simple example of undirected graph
    g <- graph_from_literal(a--b, a--c, b--c, d--e)
    plot(g)

#Connected components
#The option, mode, is ignored for undirected graphs
    comp <- components(g, mode="weak")

  
#output to a file

    fout <- file("output.txt","w")
    for(v in V(gtest)){
        vn <- V(gtest)$name[v]
        comp_id <- comp$membership[vn][[1]]
        comp_size <- comp$csize[comp_id]
        cat(sprintf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", vn, comp_id, comp_size), file=fout)
        }
    close(fout)

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Just edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to format the code as per the requirement but failed, can somebody help me out? Finally , I had to take  a screen shot and attach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like everything is vectorized and no for loop is needed. This gives the same output and uses `data.table::fwrite`, which will be quite a bit faster than `cat`.

```
vv = V(g)
vn = vv$name
comp_id = comp$membership[vv$name]
comp_size = comp$csize[comp_id]
data.table::fwrite(data.table(vn, comp_id, comp_size), "output.txt", col.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

If you don't want the data table dependency, you could use `base::write.table`, which would still be better than pasting together strings with tabs yourself.

Comment: Many thanks for doing this. I have checked with a few test data with the code I shared and your one by comparing the system.time function and found comparatively quite faster execution. But, with my real data (with 2.8 million lines) its still running for two days now without any sign of completion. First I thought the loop in R is slow, but now using functions having the same result left me a being a total clueless! :(

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem, i.e. how to write 3 millions of (short) lines into a text file. I found that using `writeChar` speed up increasingly the file writting process (from several minutes to seconds).

Below, I replaced `cat` by `writeChar` in your code:

```
g <- graph_from_literal(a--b, a--c, b--c, d--e)
plot(g)

#Connected components
#The option, mode, is ignored for undirected graphs
comp <- components(g, mode = "weak")


# first clean the file if it exists
fout <- file("output.txt", "wb")
close(fout)

# switch in appending mode
fout <- file("output.txt", "ab")

for (v in V(g)) {
  
  vn <- V(g)$name[v]
  comp_id <- comp$membership[vn][[1]]
  comp_size <- comp$csize[comp_id]
  # set eos = NULL to avoid NULL terminators
  writeChar(sprintf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", vn, comp_id, comp_size), con = fout, eos = NULL)
}

close(fout)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Caveat emptor: I don't have any of your data, so this is untested.)

Instead of doing the write *each time* within your loop, instead generate a vector of the strings (one file-line each) and write once at the end. This type of file I/O is much more efficient.

```
all_lines <- sapply(V(g), function(v) {
  vn <- V(g)$name[v]
  comp_id <- comp$membership[vn][[1]]
  comp_size <- comp$csize[comp_id]
  sprintf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", vn, comp_id, comp_size)
})
writeLines(all_lines, "output.txt")
```

The use of `sapply` is one efficiency of R, doing things as "vectors of things". Though it is not strictly necessary (this could be done with a `for` loop, though several precautions need to be taken in order to *not* be grossly inefficient, especially when dealing with a million lines), once one can "grok" the intent of vector-mechanics, it might become easier to understand and deal with.

Comment: Many thanks for doing this. I have checked with a few test data with the code I shared and your one by comparing the system.time function and found comparatively quite faster execution. But, with my real data (with 2.8 million lines) its still running for two days now without any sign of completion. First I thought the loop in R is slow, but now using functions having the same result left me a being a total clueless! :(